# Algebraic inequality 3

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If we have the following expressions

1.) $AX-BY$

2.) $(A-B)(X-Y)$

$\forall A>B$ and $X,Y\geq0$, can an inequality be established between (1) and (2).

Comment: Hello. I'm not absolutely sure of what you are expecting but have you tried to expand expression 2. and compare that result to 1. ?

Comment: I have, but i am not sure what the relationship is going to be. Basically I want to know if (1) can be upperbounded by (2)?

Answer (score 0):

For arbitrary positive $X$ and $Y$ you  must compare the prefactors of the $X$-term and the $Y$-term in both expressions to establish an inequality. For the $X$-term, you  have $A > A - B$ (supposing B > 0) so the $X$-term in the first expression is always larger than in the second. To be consistent, the same must hold for the $Y$-term, so you must have
$-B > - (A - B)$ which amounts to $A > 2B$, but you only have $A>B$. So you can construct an example where no clear relations between the two expressions exist. Set $A=3$ and $B=2$. Then the first expression becomes

$3X - 2Y$ and the second becomes $X-Y$. Equality is obtained for $2X = Y$. If $2X > Y$, the first expression is larger,   and if $2X < Y$, the second expression is larger, so you cannot establish an inequality.

You COULD establish an inequality if $A > 2B \geq 0$. Then the first expression would always be larger than the second.